# yii2 сохранение нескольких одинаковых атрибутов одной модели

Tags: php, yii2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Отдельная таблица Bayer, которая содержит имя, пароль, отдельная таблица Phone, которая содержит bayer_id и собственно значение Value, связь один ко многим.

Использую [решение](https://github.com/unclead/yii2-multiple-input) для загрузки сразу нескольких одинаковых данных в БД, но не получается сохранить полученные данные.

view:

```
...
echo $form->field($phone, 'value')->widget(MultipleInput::className(), [
    'max'               => 6,
    'min'               => 1, // should be at least 2 rows
    'allowEmptyList'    => false,
    'enableGuessTitle'  => false,
    'addButtonPosition' => MultipleInput::POS_HEADER 
])
    ->label('Телефон');
```

controller:

```
...
$phone = new Phone();
$data = Yii::$app->request->post();

if ($phone ->load($data)){
    $phone->save();
    var_dumb($phone);
}
```

но, разумеется, так не сохраняет, `var_damp($phone)` в контроллере показывает следующее:

```
...
object(common\models\Phone)#115 (9) {
    ["_attributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
    array(2) {
        ["value"]=>
         array(3) {
            [0]=>
               string(5) "12345"
            [1]=>
               string(5) "54321"
            [2]=>
               string(4) "1357"
      }
        ...
```

Есть ли здоровое решение этой проблемы? Очень не хочется городить костыли и уж темболее изобретать велосипед, но своими силами не получается, поиск не помог

`$phone->getErrors()` говорит, что данные для Phone должны быть строкой, что, собственно, логично

Answer (score 1):

Я для подобных ситуаций использую данные в поле БД в JSON формате.

Например, если мы потенциально знаем, что у пользователя может быть несколько телефонов, при этом мы не планируем реализовывать поиск или выборку по номеру телефона (иначе это затормозит код), можно сделать следующее:

Добавляем в таблицу `Bayer` поле `phones`

В модели `Bayer` прописываем публичный метод BeforeSave, где будем конвертировать массив телефонов в JSON

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
            $this->phone = json_encode($this->phone);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Кроме этого не забываем сюда же добавить метод afterFind, чтобы не мучиться каждый раз с переобразованием JSON обратно в массив

```
public function afterFind() {
    $this->phone = json_decode($this->phone, true);
}
```

Для решения конкретно Вашей проблемы в Вашем коде, Вы пытаетесь использовать метод save для более, чем одно записи, что неверно, поэтому Вам нужно пропустить $data через цикл:

```
$phone = new Phone();
$data = Yii::$app->request->post();
foreach ($data as $item) {
if ($phone ->load($item)){
    $phone->save();
} 
}
```

Либо используйте batchInsert https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27355262/activerecord-batch-insert-yii2